# How to get a list of lists that meet a certain requirement using recursion?

Tags: python, list, recursion, permutation

I have a list of words that are subsets of a string

for example if the string was  **'abb'**

the list would be

**['a','ab','b']**

and i want to create a list of lists that add up to the original string. So one of the lists' letter count in the list of lists must exactly equal the letter count in the string

so for the given example one would be **['b','ab']**

There is a helper function that keeps track of the letter in each string so the letters can be considered as numbers and can be added in a straight forward fashion like **'b' + 'ab' == 'abb'** would be considered **True**

I am new to recursion and I cannot think of a way to create this function, please help.

Full Example:

```
string = 'office key'
lst_of_possibilities = ['icky', 'fee', 'coy', 'key', 'ice', 'office', 'fief', 'icy', 'iffy', 'eye', 'foe', 'eke', 'yoke', 'coffee', 'coke', 'off', 'foci', 'fife']
```

and after the function ends the output is:

```
[['eke', 'icy', 'off'], ['eke', 'off', 'icy'], ['ice', 'key', 'off'], ['ice', 'off', 'key'], ['icy', 'eke', 'off'], ['icy', 'off', 'eke'], ['key', 'ice', 'off'], ['key', 'off', 'ice'], ['key', 'office'], ['off', 'eke', 'icy'], ['off', 'ice', 'key'], ['off', 'icy', 'eke'], ['off', 'key', 'ice'], ['office', 'key']]
```

So the point i am trying to make is that every list in the list of lists above adds up to make the word 'office key'

Comment: Looks like you want a list of list as result but I see no such structure in the question. Can you give a complete example with the all your input data and the desired list of lists?

Comment: I dont under stand the question..

Comment: @TanayÖnder you question is really confused....  I think you want some loop with some result similar to ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'da', 'db', 'dc', 'dd']

check:


a = ["a","b","c","d"]

b = []

counter1 = len(a)
counter2 = -1
for l in a:
    while counter2 != len(a)-1:
        for i in a:            
            while counter1 != 0:
                b.append(a[counter2+1] + a[counter1-1])
                counter1 -=1
            counter2 +=1
            counter1 = len(a)
b.sort()
print(b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most stupid way to do this is probably the following:
Let the string to be *s* and the list of words to be *p*

```
s = "office key"
p = ['icky', 'fee', 'coy', 'key', 'ice', 'office', 'fief', 'icy', 'iffy', 'eye', 'foe', 'eke', 'yoke', 'coffee', 'coke', 'off', 'foci', 'fife']
res_list = []
s = "".join(s.split())
n = len(p)
for mask in range(2**n):
    str = ""
    cur_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        if mask & (2**i) > 0:
             str += p[i]
             cur_list.append(p[i])
             if len(str) > len(s):
                 break
             bad = 0
             for ch in p[i]:
                if ch not in s:
                    bad = 1
                    break
             if bad == 1:
                break
    ok = 1
    for ch in s:
        if ch == " ":
            continue
        pos = str.find(ch)
        if pos == -1:
            ok = 0
            break
        else:
            str = str[:pos] + str[(pos+1):]
    if len(str) > 0:
        ok = 0
    if ok == 1:
        res_list.append(cur_list)

print res_list
```

This is a little bit optimized bruteforce search which is I think is ok for you specific problem since you want exactly the list of all possible solutions.

P.S. You have all permutations for each specific output which can be achieved faster just at the end outputing all permutations for each list in res_list